# ClickOnce & TFS Automated Build and Deployments

Tags: clickonce, build-automation, tfs

I have an application that we use internally that is deployed through ClickOnce.  We have 5 locations that I deploy the Install to manually by changing the Location Settings and running the Publish 5 times.

We have TFS 2010 but I am unfamiliar with using it for anything besides Source Control.  I would like to explore the possibility of using Team Foundation Server (2010) to accomplish this.  Is this something TFS is capable of doing if configured correctly?

Comment: I do know that you could use an msbuild script to do what you're looking for. However, I'm still a bit of a scrub with msbuild, so I can't give you any more details than that. It's an avenue of research though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a peek into MSBuild and its XML based schema/configuration. At a previous position, I had a MSBuild task setup to push out ClickOnce deployments with ease, once you nailed one getting the 4 others would be simple repetition. I recall MSBuild having a bit of a learning curve.

Helpful links:

[Building ClickOnce Applications from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165431%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Publishing a ClickOnce project with command-line MSBuild](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/40bb7d32-a9ad-40d7-8113-cb3ed2747e69)

I don't doubt that TFS has something useful for MSBuild, an GUI based setup perhaps, but I cannot say.

Comment: Can you sum up what MSBuild does for me vs ClickOnce or is that a seperate post?  I always thought you used one or the other.

Comment: @Refracted Paladin: ClickOnce publishes the application (and provides updating features etc.), after msbuild builds/compiles it. It only gets a bit fuzzy when you consider all of the msbuild tasks available goes far beyond just building the application. (http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ for example)

Comment: From what I understand, you can use MSBuild to build your app, and it wraps mage to sign the manifests. Then it will copy the files to a file share, but not to a webserver, so you would have to find another way to automate that bit, like use some kind of script.

Comment: MSBuild is pretty flexible, you can copy also, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx.